# libpython2.6.so.1.0 is needed when install impala 2.0 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, impala

I have already install hadoop 2.7 from apache,then tried to install impala 2.0 from rpms.the impala/statestore/catalog is ok, but when install impala-shell Here i run into a problem as follows:

> error: Failed dependencies:   libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit) is needed by impala-shell-2.0.0-1.impala2.0.0.p0.203.el6.x86_64

The default python version of centos 7 is python2.7, then I download source python 2.6.6 ,compile it to produce a libpython2.6.so,and create the soft link.
But when I execute **sudo rpm -ivh impala-shell-2.0.0-1.impala2.0.0.p0.203.el6.x86_64.rpm**
the problem is still there.

What can I do to fix this problem?